# What was the format for personal sites hosted with (deprecated) .Mac?

Tags: mac, mobileme

I can't find any leads on what the URL formatting was for websites hosted as part of the [.Mac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MobileMe#.Mac) offerings. I'd like to find my old one and see if it was archived by the Wayback Machine, but don't remember the syntax (i.e. http://web.mac.com/~handle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## homepage.mac.com

The format was http://homepage.mac.com/sitehost/penrithfire and at least some of the pages are in the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20040615000000*/homepage.mac.com/sitehost/penrithfire).

This `penrithfire` example came from a signature in a [discussion from 2003](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/589341) about dot Mac.